# How to get dynamic form submission record count in Orchard CMS

Tags: c#, orchardcms, submission, dynamicform

I made a register page with dynamic form in **Orchard CMS**, and received new requirements of checking record count.

I have no idea about how to do this, I looked into the `SubmissionAdminController.cs` in `Orchard.DynamicForms.Controllers` folder, but still could not find a way.

I'm thinking to get the record count from my `cshtml` view page and check it in different parts, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

To get the record count of the stored submissions, inject or resolve an `IRepository<Submission>`, and use the `Count()` method to count all items. Note that the `Count()` method accepts an expression, which allows you to filter by form name for example. For reference, this is what the `Submission` class looks like:

```
namespace Orchard.DynamicForms.Models {
    public class Submission {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string FormName { get; set; }

        [StringLengthMax]
        public virtual string FormData { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime CreatedUtc { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When you have an `IRepository<Submission>`, this is how you would count all submissions in a form called "MyForm":

```
var count = submissionRepository.Count(x => x.FormName == "MyForm");
```

If you don't have a controller or custom part or anything to inject this IRepository into, then you could resolve the repository directly form your view like this:

```
@{
    var submissionRepository = WorkContext.Resolve<IRepository<Submission>>();
    var submissionCount = submissionRepository.Count(x => x.FormName == "MyForm");
}
```

Make sure to import the proper namespaces:

- `Orchard.DynamicForms.Models` for `Submission`
- `Orchard.Data` for `IRepository<T>`

However, if you need to display this number in multiple places, it's best to create a shape so that you can reuse it. Even better would be to not resolve the repository from the shape template directly, but via an `IShapeTableProvider`. The primary reason for that becomes clear when you start overriding your shape template or start providing shape alternates, both in which cases you'll have duplicate logic in all of your shape templates, which isn't very DRY of course. And there's the more philosophical issue of separation of concerns: you don't want data access code in your views. Rather, use that code from a controller, driver or shape table provider.

Comment: You should grant the answer then ;)

Comment: I am sorry that I clicked the useful up button but without enough reputation.